# Sustituto de Files.readAllBytes y .toPath() para Android

Tags: android

Tengo las siguientes líneas en mi app en una clase que actúa como `AsyncTask` para incluir una imagen en el cuerpo de una consulta `HTTP`.

Tengo el siguiente objeto `File`:

```
val file = File(getContext().cacheDir, "fileName")
file.createNewFile()
```

y después con un `FileOutputStream` escribo un `BitMap`en ese fichero de tal forma:

```
val fos = FileOutputStream(file)
fos.write(bitMapData)
fos.flush()
fos.close()
```

Y por último, para escribir todos los bytes en el `request` de la consulta, utilizo:

```
val bytes = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath())
request.write(bytes) //La variable request es el OutputStream del objeto HttpUrlConnection
```

Estas dos funciones, `readAllBytes()` y `toPath()` me piden una API mínima de 26, que es muy alta, cuál sería su sustituto para API más pequeñas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como bien comentas [Files.readAllBytes()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes(java.nio.file.Path)) se agrego a partir de la API 26.

Puedes configurar tu proyecto con:

`compileSdkVersion=26` y `targetSdkVersion=26`

Si deseas un código para APIs anteriores :

```
File file = new File("<ruta de archivo>");

     byte[] b = new byte[(int) file.length()];
     try {
           FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
           fileInputStream.read(b);
           for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
                       System.out.print((char)b[i]);
            }
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                  System.out.println("No existe archivo en ruta especificada.");
                  e.printStackTrace();
      }
      catch (IOException ioe) {
               System.out.println("Error Reading The File.");
                ioe.printStackTrace();
      }
```

Comment: La idea sería buscar un método equivalente para APIs más pequeñas, que me funcione por ejemplo con una API 24

Comment: Agregue una forma de realizaron con apis inferiores a 26.

Comment: Genial, muchas gracias, me funciona, pero tengo una duda sobre el comportamiento. Realmente, lo que le tengo que pasar a `response` por parámetros el es `ByteArray` (`b`) por lo que llegué a pensar que el objeto `FileInputStream` no lo necesitaría, así que lo borré, pero si lo borró no me funciona.. sabes a qué se debe?